# Black-listing client side certificates in Apache2?

Tags: apache-httpd, openssl, nginx, certificates, https

Is there a way to **black-list** a client-side certificate issued to an specific user?

I currently have a case where a few malicious actors have my website's client side certificates and I do not know how stop them from using it.

I currently run `Apache2` on a CentOS machine but can migrate to `NGINX` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the CA which issued the certificate to revoke it.  The CA (should) regularly issues a [Certificate Revocation List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_revocation_list) (CRL), which is, in essence, a black-list of certificates that any relying party (your Apache server in this case) should not trust.

You can check if your CA issues CRL by looking for the CRL Distribution Point extension:

```
$ openssl x509 -noout -text -in example.crt | grep -A1 "Full Name"

            Full Name:
              URI:http://pki.example.test/cdp/example-CA.crl
```

The URL is where the relying party can download the CRL.

Alternatively, the CA could be using [OCSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol) to distribute revocation information.  This is a more complex system, where the relying-party queries the responder for the revocation status of a particular certificate.  You can find this using:

```
$ openssl x509 -noout -text -in example.crt | grep "OCSP"

                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.example.test
```

This is the URL of the OCSP responder.

If you don't see either of these, then the CA isn't issuing revocation information and you're most probably out of luck.

However, Apache has the **SSLCARevocationFile** option which can point to a CRL downloaded via some alternative method.  In the unlikely event that the CA generates CRLs, but doesn't distribute them by either methods above, but is willing to email it to you, for example; you could save this to the server and point Apache to it with this option.  Unlikely, I'd suggest.

Answer (score 0):

After the help from `garethTheRed`. I wrote a Python script that helps you revoke client side certificates. Since I was my own certificate authority (CA) I could easily get my hands on CA private key which is needed in order to update my CRL.

You if anyone is having similar issues. You can find my code on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/megamorphf/13af9e0d0321fcfc0c787aaed4a86888)